# Saving in 300dpi Script

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'am using a script but its saving images in 96dpi. Is tehere any way to save them in 300dpi ? If it is not possible, please help me on how to save it as PSD with this script. Because then I can get 300dpi images from psd files with image processor.

Thanks.

This is the script :

```
  #target photoshop
if (app.documents.length > 0) {
    var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
    var theName = myDocument.name.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];
    var thePath = myDocument.path;
    var theLayer = myDocument.activeLayer;
    // JPG Options;
    jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();  
    jpgSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;  
    jpgSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;  
    jpgSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;  
    jpgSaveOptions.quality = 12;   
    // Check if layer is SmartObject;
    if (theLayer.kind != "LayerKind.SMARTOBJECT") {
        alert("selected layer is not a smart object")
    } else {
        // Select Files;
        if ($.os.search(/windows/i) != -1) {
            var theFiles = File.openDialog("please select files", "*.psd;*.tif;*.jpg", true)
        } else {
            var theFiles = File.openDialog("please select files", getFiles, true)
        };
        if (theFiles) {
            for (var m = 0; m < theFiles.length; m++) {
                // Replace SmartObject
                theLayer = replaceContents(theFiles[m], theLayer);
                var theNewName = theFiles[m].name.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];
                // Save JPG. If you have need of saving different artboards into separate files,
                // see https://gist.github.com/laryn/0a1f6bf0dab5b713395a835f9bfa805c#gistcomment-3996733
// Export each top layer group (artboards) as a JPG
var destStatics = new Folder(activeDocument.path + '/../assets/static-banners/')
var doc = activeDocument;
if (!destStatics.exists) {
  destStatics.create();
}

(function getLayers(el) {
// find layer groups
  var today = new Date();
  var time = today.getHours() + "-" + today.getMinutes() + "-" + today.getSeconds();
  var theNewName = theFiles[m].name.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];
  for (var a = 0; a < el.layerSets.length; a++) {
    var lname = el.layerSets[a].name;
    var exportName = '';
    if (time + lname != 'Null' && lname != 'NULL' && time + lname != 'null') {
      var ext = time + lname.substr(-4);
      if (ext === '.jpg') {
var exportName = time + lname;
      } else if (ext === '.jpg') {
var exportName = time + name.replace('.png', '.jpg')
      } else {
var exportName = lname + theNewName + '.jpg'
      }
      saveLayer(el.layers.getByName(lname), exportName, destStatics, true);
    }
  }
})(doc)

function saveLayer(layer, lname, path, shouldMerge) {
  activeDocument.activeLayer = layer;
  dupLayers();
  if (shouldMerge === undefined || shouldMerge === true) {
    activeDocument.mergeVisibleLayers();
  }
  activeDocument.trim(TrimType.TRANSPARENT,true,true,true,true);
  var saveFile = File(path + "/" + lname);
  SaveJPG(saveFile);
  app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}

function dupLayers() {
  var desc143 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var ref73 = new ActionReference();
  ref73.putClass( charIDToTypeID('Dcmn') );
  desc143.putReference( charIDToTypeID('null'), ref73 );
  desc143.putString( charIDToTypeID('Nm  '), activeDocument.activeLayer.name );
  var ref74 = new ActionReference();
  ref74.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), charIDToTypeID('Ordn'), charIDToTypeID('Trgt') );
  desc143.putReference( charIDToTypeID('Usng'), ref74 );
  executeAction( charIDToTypeID('Mk  '), desc143, DialogModes.NO );
};

function SaveJPG(saveFile){
  var sfwOptions = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();   
  sfwOptions.format = SaveDocumentType.JPEG;   
  sfwOptions.includeProfile = false;   
  sfwOptions.interlaced = false;   
  sfwOptions.optimized = true;   
  sfwOptions.quality = 100;
  activeDocument.exportDocument( saveFile, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, sfwOptions );
}            }
        }
    }
};
// Get PSDs, TIFs and JPGs from files
function getFiles(theFile) {
    if (theFile.name.match(/\.(psd|tif|jpg)$/i) != null || theFile.constructor.name == "Folder") {
        return true
    };
};
// Replace SmartObject Contents
function replaceContents(newFile, theSO) {
    app.activeDocument.activeLayer = theSO;
    // =======================================================
    var idplacedLayerReplaceContents = stringIDToTypeID("placedLayerReplaceContents");
    var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
    desc3.putPath(idnull, new File(newFile));
    var idPgNm = charIDToTypeID("PgNm");
    desc3.putInteger(idPgNm, 1);
    executeAction(idplacedLayerReplaceContents, desc3, DialogModes.NO);
    return app.activeDocument.activeLayer
};
```

Comment: You say the script is saving jpegs at a resolution of 96dpi. Does the output file match the original in absolute pixels? If the input and output files are both 4000x3000px then resolution in ppi/dpi is meaningless, and the files are the same size.

Comment: First you’re using `JPEGSaveOptions()` that allows saving jpegs at the document dpi, but then you switch to `ExportOptionsSaveForWeb()` that doesn’t allow that. What’s the logic?

Comment: Thanx but i didnt write this script :( just seeking for solution.

Comment: The solution is to use `JPEGSaveOptions()`